# Has anyone tried putting PHP ActiveRecord on Wordpress?

Tags: php, database, forms, code, mvc

I have worked with Ruby on Rails and I was looking for some code that did something close to the wonderfull RoR's ActiveRecord.

I stepped by [this site](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/). Its PHP-ActiveRecord!

I found it amazing, and it was exactly what I was looking for, but I didn't find anyone trying to use it on WordPress, so I got a little scared.

Any experiences you could share?

My first idea was to require the library in functions.php and create a child theme with the models inside a folder. What I really don't know is how it's going to deal with the tables in the database it can't mess with.

Well, I'll wait your impressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to use it just for your own code, and have it running alongside WordPress' default database driver (`wpdb`), I see no real problems.

It's only if you plan on fully integrating/overriding WP's driver that I see it being near-impossible; hard-coded SQL is prolific throughout core, and translating them to ActiveRecord method calls would defeat any efforts for code optimisation.

FWIW, WordPress does support a driver override with `db.php` in your `wp-content` directory.

**Update:** For bringing PHP ActiveRecord into WordPress, I would suggest using a MU plugin. This keeps it out of the theme (where it doesn't belong), out of WordPress core, and ensures that it is always loaded (**M**ust **U**se plugins cannot be deactivated in the admin).

Copy the library to `wp-content/mu-plugins/php-activerecord`. Then in `wp-content/mu-plugins/php-activerecord.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: PHP ActiveRecord
 * Description: Load the PHP ActiveRecord library for use in plugins &amp; themes.
 * Version:     0.1
 * Author:      TheDeadMedic
 * Author URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155530
 */

require_once dirname( __file__ ) . '/php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(
    function ( $cfg ) {
        $cfg->set_model_directory( '/path/to/your/model_directory' );
        $cfg->set_connections(
            array(
                'wordpress' => sprintf( 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=%s', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_CHARSET ),
            )
        );

        $cfg->set_default_connection( 'wordpress' );
    }
);
```

Comment: Its intended for my code only. To use alongside wpdb, because the plugins, themes, etc, will continue to use wpdb normally. For this use, does the process I described make sense to you? Any other tip?

Comment: Are you coding your own theme, or developing a child theme based on an existing one?

Comment: I'm using a theme called Divi. I didn't intend to create a child theme. I'm just adding php on it in functions.php and on certain parts of the pages using a plugin that inserts php. I'm doing a kind of MVC. Controllers and routes went well, but for models, the ActiveRecord would be a dream.

Comment: I would strongly recommend [using a child theme](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial). See my revised answer for a suggestion on how to integrate PHP AR.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! I'll try it out and comment the results! You're a guru, TheDeadMedic!

Comment: That works really nice. I wonder why more people don't use it this way.

Comment: [PHPactiverecord][1] is a dead project since 2013.

Try to use models from [WPMVC][2] instead.

http://wpmvc.org/documentation/models/


  [1]: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/
  [2]: http://wpmvc.org/

Answer (score 1):

[PHPactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) is a dead project since 2013.

Try to use models from [WPMVC](http://wpmvc.org/) instead.

http://wpmvc.org/documentation/models/