# Simple form validation for custom post type in front end. Not working

Tags: forms

So everything is working fine except for the validation.  The error messages don't display when the form is submitted empty and you can still submit the form when empty.  I must be missing something really obvious.  I've already spent a few hours scouring the web and have tried several fixes myself to no avail.  Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<?php add_shortcode('testimonial-form', 'testimonial_form_sc') ?>

<?php function testimonial_form_sc(){ ?>

<div class="row">
<h3>Send Us Your Testimonial</h3>
<form id="add_testimonial" name="add_testimonial" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!-- post name -->

    <label for="username" style="display:block">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="username" style="display-block" />

<!-- post content -->
    <label for="description" style="display:block">Testimonial:</label>
    <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>

    <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">

    <input class="small-button" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" style="display:block;"/>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_testimonial" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>

</div> 

<?php

if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&     $_POST['action'] == "add_testimonial") {

// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if (isset ($_POST['username'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['username'];
} 
else {
    echo 'Please enter your name';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} 
else {
    echo 'Please enter your testimonial';
}

// add the form input to $new_testimonial array
$new_testimonial = array(
'post_title'    =>   $title,
'post_content'  =>   $description,
'post_status'   =>   'publish',           // Switch this to draft if you want to moderate posts
'post_type' =>   'testimonial'  //post type to insert the post into
);

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_testimonial);

// Upload image for post thumbnail

 if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            }   
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($pid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }

include 'validate-image-size.php';

//Redirect to the new post on save
$link = get_permalink( $pid );
wp_redirect( $link );

}} // End of the if statement that started the form and the end of the shortcode     [testimonial-form]

//post the post
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation is not working because the variables with the empty array return true with isset;

Go to http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and try this code, and you'll understand:

```
$test = "";
if ( isset($test) ){
    echo "true";
}
```

The right function for it, instead of isset is empty. Try it out:

```
$test = "";
if ( empty($test) ){
    echo "empty";
}
```

Further, if you're doing lots of modelling and validations in wordpress, I suggest using the wonderfull PHPActiveRecord.
I learned how to use it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155484/has-anyone-tried-putting-php-activerecord-on-wordpress), and I'm in love with it. :)

Comment: That makes sense now!  Thanks for your help.  I looked at PHPActiveRecord and it looks great.  I'll look into a little further today.  Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, you can use jQuery validations, if you need something quicker, but, since I came from Ruby On Rails, I really enjoyed working with this modeling architecture. I've put this on wordpress and it's helping a lot!